# Execute dynamic query in stored prouder oracle Rdb

Tags: sql, oracle-rdb

I want to execute one dynamic update query in oracle rdb through stored procedure.

For example:

Set `:updateString='Update table set colum1, column2':`

I want to execute `:updateString` in procedure only.

I have tried below cmds

```
Exec :updateString
execute :updateString, 
exec sql :updateString
```

and so on but nothing is working in oracle rdb sql terminal.

I am using Oracle Rdb (a relational database management system for the OpenVMS operating system).
Version is Oracle Rdb SQL On Openvms Release 7.4.1.0.0

Comment: Just to make sure: you're really using Oracle Rdb (a relational database management system for the OpenVMS operating system). Right?

Comment: Is really `Update table set colum1, column2` valid RDB syntax? Don't you have to assign values to the columns?

Comment: @Littlefoot:Yes

Comment: @jarlh:yes I will assign some values so it is like update table set column1='test1', column2='test2' ;